# Behavior of __all__ in __init__ on Python when used to import modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python package of the form:

```
package
├── __init__.py
├── module_1.py
└── module_2.py
```

Inside __init__.py I have:

```py
__all__ = ["module_1", "module_2"]
```

Module_1 is:

```py
__all__ = ["foo"]
def foo(): pass
```

Module_2 is:

```py
__all__ = ["Bar"]
class Bar: pass
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) I thought that the following code would import `foo` and `Bar`:

```py
import package as pk
```

However, when I run `pk.foo()` it throws an error: `AttributeError: module 'package' has no attribute 'foo'` (same for Bar).

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710527/12384807) answer, I know that to get the desired behavior, I can change __init__.py into:

```py
from .module_1 import *
from .module_2 import *
```

The above works.

However, **I do not understand the** [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package). The lines:

> if a package’s __init__.py code defines a list named __all__, it is taken to be the list of **module names** that should be imported when from package import * is encountered

Sound like my original __init__.py should have worked (the one with `__all__ = ["module_1", "module_2"]`). That is, the line `import package as pk` should have imported the **modules** `module_1` and `module_2`, which in turn make `foo` and `Bar` available.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I have also tried using exactly what the documentation mentions. That is, using `from package import *`, and then tried with `package.foo()` and `foo()`, but neither worked.

The first, `package.foo()`, throws the error `NameError: 'package' is not defined.`. The second, `foo()`, throws the error `NameError: 'foo' is not defined.`.

How would a working example look like?.. One where __init__.py is of the form __all__ = ["module_1", "module_2"].

Comment: First off, you should be looking at the Python 3 documentation. I've changed the URL in your question.

Comment: It says "when `from package import *` is encountered", not "when `import package` is encountered".

Comment: That is right.. I tried that too, but it didn't work either. I tried using `package.foo()` and just `foo()`, after `from package import *`. But neither worked.

Comment: Plus, even if it triggered on `import package`, that still wouldn't have dumped the contents of `package.module_1` and `package.module_2` into the `package` namespace.

Comment: You're mixing up the behavior of `import whatever` and `from whatever import *` all over the place.

Comment: How would a working example look like? Where `__init__.py` is of the form `__all__ = ["module_1", "module_2"]`?.. Or is it only possible by using `from .module_1 import *` in `__init__`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone explain \_\_all\_\_ in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, it does not. I actually reference that same post in my question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, that is true for regular modules, but the `__init__.py` file behaves different. See my next comment.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I just did the following test: I added `print("Imported module_1")` inside `module_1`, and then ran `from package import *`. It printed the statement. So it is essentially working: It is importing the module. You are then right when saying "even if it triggered on import package, that still wouldn't have dumped the contents of package.module_1 and package.module_2 into the package namespace.". How would I achieve that behavior then? Or is it simply not meant to be used in this way?

Comment: @AndresSilva you're right, I learned something new today. But in this case, what becomes available when you `from package import *` is `module_1`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, You are right! I can then use `module_1.foo()`. I guess I finally got how it works. But it would be nice to add all of this into a succinct Answer, to help future pythoners.

Comment: in simple term, whatevery you define in `__all__` you can import those module/function/variable from that level only nothing else

Answer (score 6):

I will try to summarize the knowledge gained from the comments to my question, the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), my own tests, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710527/12384807) post.

### 1) `__all__` behaves differently on `__init__` and modules

#### 1.1) Within a module

When `__all__` is within a **module**, it determines what objects are made available when running `from module import *`.

Given this package structure:

```
package
├── __init__.py
├── module_1.py
└── module_2.py
```

And given the following code for `module_1`:

```py
__all__ = ["foo"]
def foo(): pass
def baz(): pass
```

Running `from package.module_1 import *` will make **`foo`** available **but not `baz`**.

Moreover, **`foo`** can then be called using `foo()`, i.e., there is no need to reference the module.

#### 1.2) Within `__init__` (my original question)

When `__all__` is within `__init__`,

> it is taken to be the list of **module names** that **should be imported** when **from package import *** is encountered.

Running `from package import *` will then have two effects:

1. The scripts of the modules in `__all__` will be ran (they are imported).
2. These modules are made available in the namespace.

This means that if `__init__` is of the form:

```py
__all__ = ["module_1", "module_2"]
```

Then, running `from package import *` will run the scripts of `module_1` and `module_2` and **make both modules available**. So, now, the function `foo` inside `module_1` can be called as `module_1.foo()` **instead of** `package.module_1.foo()`.

However, if this is the intent, then using `from package.module_1 import foo` might be better. As it makes `foo` accessible as `foo()`.

### 2) `from package import *` is not the same as `import package`

Running `from package import *` has the effect mentioned in **1.2)**. However, this is not true for running `import package`: i.e. `module_1.foo()` would not work in this scenario.

### 3) The alternative approach to `__init__`

(The following is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710527/12384807) post) As I mentioned in my question, there is an alternative approach to `__init__`, in which the objects that you want to make available when the user calls `from package import *` are **directly imported into `__init__`.**

As an example, `__init__` could contain the following code:

```py
from .module_1 import *
from .module_2 import *
```

Then, when the user calls `from package import *` the objects from modules 1 and 2 would be available on the namespace.

If `module_1` was that of **1.1)**, then the function `foo` could be called without referencing the module. i.e. `foo()`. However, the same would not work for `baz`.

As mentioned in **2)**, `from package import *` is different to `import package`. Calling `import package` in this scenario (with this `__init__`), makes foo available through `package.foo()`, **instead of** just `foo()`. Similarly `import package as pk` makes foo available as `pk.foo()`.

This approach could be preferable to that of **1.2)**, in which `foo` is made available through `module_1.foo()`.

Comment: Your 1.2 is wrong, it will *NOT* just affect modules in the package. The wording in the documentation is misleading (see my https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/106556)

Answer (score -3):

The key problem in your code is that you have defined `__all__` in sub modules. Which allows to be exported only that module, but such module is not available in your directory. They are definitions you want to use.

So, just remove them from sub modules and you'll get it working.

Comment: No, removing `__all__` from the submodules won't change that behavior at all.

Comment: That is what blocking to export definitions.